# Meteor Cordova, How do I query the database?

Tags: mongodb, cordova, mobile, meteor

I am trying out ios apps built using Cordova and Meteor. Normally when I build a Meteor App, I can see the database's fields and structures by making a mongo query in the browser console, or opening genghisapp to see the entire database. But now I'm testing out the mobile apps by plugging in my iphone and running the test app there. How can I see the structure of my data and documents on there?

Comment: There is no way to see the data on a device because they aren't any console available.

What can be done is that, you can put the console.log i.e. inserting the logs into a database and then looking the same on the server. I have created several meteorjs apps which does the same.

Comment: How have you been viewing your database? I usually use genghisapp, any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're running meteor on the iPhone, you're app should still be available at localhost:3000 (unless you're doing something fancy with the --mobile-server) and be connected to the same database your iPhone is using. You could run your browser console queries in the browser and it will update/reflect whats going on in the mobile app. I used this when debugging my latest project and it works as well as using the browser console while testing out a web app.

I'll have to take a look and see if this same thing can be done with genghisapp but if you're open to alternatives check out this package

https://github.com/gterrono/houston/

it's a simple auto-magical admin dashboard that might be a good substitute for genghisapp and I know the houston package will work when you're running meteor on you phone.